# XML serialization node coming twice

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

In my c# code I am trying to use XML serialization instead of xml linq. I am not sure which one is better.

But for now the issue I am having is that my node is coming twice. So this is my class structure

```
public class Enterprise
{
    public Properties properties;
    public List<Person> person;
}
```

This is the xml I get generated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<enterprise>
<properties lang="nb">
<Comments>Utlasting av LMS-data</Comments>
<Datasource>SIKT</Datasource>
<Target />
<Datetime>onsdag 24. oktober 2018</Datetime>
</properties>
<person>
<Person>
  <sourceid>
    <Source>AD</Source>
    <Id>123</Id>
  </sourceid>
  <Userid>mohsin</Userid>
</Person>
```

As you see the Person tag is coming twice. This is how it is set up

```
Enterprise enterprise = new Enterprise();
enterprise.properties.LanguageCode = "nb";
enterprise.properties.Comments = "Utlasting av LMS-data";
enterprise.properties.Datasource = "SIKT";
enterprise.properties.Target = "";
enterprise.properties.Datetime = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();

List<Person> person = new List<Person>();


person.Add(new Person
{
    //sourceid = new SourceId
    //{
    //    Id = "123",
    //    Source = "AD"
    //},
    Userid = "mohsin"
});

enterprise.person = person;
```

Does anyone knows the reason?

Comment: You have person in persons list. If you rename your person property to more meaningful persons or listOfPersons you will see what's going on.

Comment: But how do I avoid it? I don't need that parent element wrapping all person?

Comment: @mohsinali1317 the `<memberName><itemName/>...<itemName/></memberName>` is simply the *default* behaviour - Baskar John's answer shows you how to tell it to do something different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use List or array it will conside as `XmlArrayItem' to overcome use 'XmlElement'

```
public class Enterprise
{
  public Properties properties;
  [XmlElement("person")]
  public List<Person> person;
}
```